# Verifying sent messages Firefox addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a question. I have a panel in Firefox add-on and I would like to modify things on the page when it is closed. I created a listener on the panel and a content script `close.js` that will modify the the page.

```
panel.port.on("close", function() {
    panel.port.emit("close");
});
```

What I would like to know is how can I debug and verify that the message "close" has effectively been sent  ? Because now it is not working but I have no possibility of checking what messages has been sent ?

Do I have to load `close.js` as a contentScript when I create the panel ? Knowing that there are other scripts that modify the page that are not loaded when creating the panel...

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to know is how can I debug and verify that the
>   message "close" has effectively been sent ? Because now it is not
>   working but I have no possibility of checking what messages has been
>   sent ?

You can add `addon.port.on("close", () => console.log("close message was sent to panel"))` to the content script for the panel.  Seeing this message logged will verify that the panel is receiving the "close" message.

> Do I have to load close.js as a contentScript when I create the panel
>   ? Knowing that there are other scripts that modify the page that are
>   not loaded when creating the panel...

All panel content scripts have to be added and loaded when the panel is created, there is no option to add a content script after the panel has been created.